# Not letting me change color of active title bar windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

I just downloaded [this](http://saarineames.deviantart.com/art/Classic-AE-2-5-3-Final-343638171) theme on deviantart and I like it, but the only issue is it won't let me change the active title bar color. even though in the preview it shows the color I want, once i apply the changes it just goes back to the standard blue color. I would like to change it to #d4eef7 as the first color and then blend it into #d4d8f7 as a secondary color. Here's a picture of the preview:

[image]

I would prefer it to look just like that preview, but if its easier for you I would be ok with just having #d4eef7 as the color, without the blending. thank you in advance for your help!!

Comment: I do not know for sure, but it is not "classic" it is still "skinned" so it is likely that the colors your seeing there are a picture, a part of the skin. To change it would be to grab that picture  as a resource from the skin and alter it, then put it back.

Comment: thank you for your reply! i'm very new to programming though so i don't know how to do what you suggested. i tried searching on google for how to do it but i didn't get any relevant results. would you mind telling me how or directing me to a website that could walk me through it?